# VSCode open-ssh fail : AWS (SessionManagerPlugin is no found)

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, openssh, aws-session-manager

Thank you for reading.

I successfully set up the ssh config file to loggin to the AWS.

When I try to do ssh login in my local terminal, it works well, but when I try to do using my VSCode Open-SSH extension, it always fails except the first try.

The output is like this:

```
[18:38:25.400] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 53736 -o ConnectTimeout=15 -F <config> awsserver bash
[18:38:26.521] > 
> SessionManagerPlugin is not found. Please refer to SessionManager Documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/systems-manager/session-manager-plugin-not-found
```

All aws commands are well reached from my terminal environment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps VScode can't access your systems environment variables properly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the VSCode Open-SSH extension, but appears you are getting a message from Amazon's AWS CLI as if this command was being run:

`aws ssm start-session --target i-0d2a6aaaaaaaa61c5`

Rather than using ssh, is your extension perhaps configured to use Amazon SSM?